# Perl/Tk: Aligning the text in BrowseEntry listbox

Tags: perl, user-interface, perltk

I have a BrowseEntry of which the text is right aligned as in below code.

```
my $brEntry = $mw->BrowseEntry(
                    -variable => \$var,
                    -state => 'readonly',
                    -justify => 'right'
              )->pack(-side => 'left', -expand => 'yes', -fill => 'both');
```

But the drop-down list of this BrowseEntry comes with the text left aligned. I need to right align the text inside this list also. Is there a way I can do this?

I tried by

```
$brEntry->Subwidget('slistbox')->configure(-justify => 'right');
```

But this does not work and it gives error.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.perl.tk/8JPfv6DTUc8

Comment: I don't think that this is currently possible. There was no justify option when looking into the things that can be configured: `print Dumper $be->Subwidget('slistbox')->configure();` I didn't find a justify option for the listbox widget either.